# Facebook tab displaying 404

Tags: facebook, .htaccess

I'm trying to create an application on facebook. By application i mean a tab that's going to include an external page (like an iframe).

When i'm accesing the application's link, like a page for the app itself, it's working fine. But when i'm installing the application to a regular facebook page, instead of including and displaying the external page it gives me a 404 page.

That index.php is hosted in a dir on my server. The above mentionated 404 page it's a wordpress 404 page, as i have in the root an wordpress installed. I think that all this mess has to be related with the .htaccess and the rewrite stuff from wordpress maybe.

Here's the .htaccess that's in my root right now:

```
ErrorDocument 401 default
########
php_value upload_max_filesize 50M
php_value post_max_size 50M
php_value max_execution_time 500
php_value max_input_time 500
#########
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
###Start Kloxo PHP config Area
###Please Don't edit these comments or the content in between. kloxo uses this to recognize the lines it writes to the the file. If the above line is corrupted, it may fail to recognize them, leading to multiple lines.

<Ifmodule mod_php4.c>
    php_value error_log "/home/boostermedia.ro/__processed_stats/dani2.boostermedia.ro.phplog"
    php_value upload_max_filesize 2M
    php_value max_execution_time  30
    php_value max_input_time  60
    php_value memory_limit  32M
    php_value post_max_size  8M
    php_flag register_globals  off
    php_flag display_errors  off
    php_flag file_uploads  on
    php_flag log_errors  off
    php_flag output_buffering  off
    php_flag register_argc_argv  on
    php_flag magic_quotes_gpc   off
    php_flag magic_quotes_runtime  off
    php_flag magic_quotes_sybase  off
    php_flag mysql.allow_persistent  off
    php_flag register_long_arrays  on
    php_flag allow_url_fopen  on
    php_flag cgi.force_redirect  on
    php_flag enable_dl  on
</Ifmodule>

<Ifmodule mod_php5.c>
    php_value error_log "/home/boostermedia.ro/__processed_stats/dani2.boostermedia.ro.phplog"
    php_value upload_max_filesize 2M
    php_value max_execution_time  30
    php_value max_input_time  60
    php_value memory_limit  32M
    php_value post_max_size  8M
    php_flag register_globals  off
    php_flag display_errors  off
    php_flag file_uploads  on
    php_flag log_errors  off
    php_flag output_buffering  off
    php_flag register_argc_argv  on
    php_flag magic_quotes_gpc   off
    php_flag magic_quotes_runtime  off
    php_flag magic_quotes_sybase  off
    php_flag mysql.allow_persistent  off
    php_flag register_long_arrays  on
    php_flag allow_url_fopen  on
    php_flag cgi.force_redirect  on
    php_flag enable_dl  on
</Ifmodule>

###End Kloxo PHP config Area


# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

The first line, the **ErrorDocument 401 default** was my last attemp at dealing with the 404. Here are the links:
- [the application's page](https://apps.facebook.com/beautydistrict/) - it should display a simple table
- [this is where index.php is hosted](http://www.quart.ro/beautydistrict/)
- [this is where the app is installed and the 404 error](https://www.facebook.com/darkitro/app_538467876227122)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have FB Settings issues.

1. The URL should be https://quart.ro/beautydistrict/index.php instead of https://quart.ro/beautydistrict/index.php/ . See the last slash at the end? You need to remove it.
2. You need to have SSL on your server

Hope this helps

Comment: I have a self-signed certificate, otherwise the facebook app won't work, the https urls are mandatory. About that slash, it won't work without that slash. It's either the file or the directory but it must have a slash at the end.

Comment: If you use self-signed ssl, most browsers will give warning or no content at all in iframes.